# Is there a name for this set of vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, definition

While looking at some graph theory questions, I came across a set construction and was wondering if there is a name for it.

A subset of vertices $S \subseteq V$ such that for every vertex $u \in V - S$ there exists a vertex $v \in S$ such that $uv \in E$.

Or, as I understand it more intuitively, each vertex not in this set has an adjacent vertex in this set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a [dominating set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set).

Comment: Yes, this is it, thanks for the quick response! Will accept when the timer allows